# Google Visualization not showing in JSP on google app engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jsp, google-visualization

So I want to use the visualization map from google and I want to display on my JSP generated page.  t is being hosted on Google AppEngine. When I run the JSP on Google App Engine, this is the final output that is generated.  However, after being compiled, the code looks good and when I put into google code playground, it works, but on the google app engine, it doesn't work at all!  Here is the code that is sent to the webpage.  I am at a complete loss as to how to fix this.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!
Jon

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>People</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=GOOGLEAPIKEYTHATISVALID" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geomap']});
function drawVisualization() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addRows(4);
data.addColumn('string', 'State');
data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
data.setValue(0, 0, 'Pennsylvania');
data.setValue(0, 1, 10);
data.setValue(1, 0, 'New York');
data.setValue(1, 1, 15);
data.setValue(2, 0, 'California');
data.setValue(2, 1, 5);
data.setValue(3, 0, 'New Jersey');
data.setValue(3, 1, 8);


var options = {};
options['region'] = 'US';
var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
document.getElementById('container.page-wrap.mainContent.map_canvas'));
geomap.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body > ##I have also done <body onload="drawVisualization()"> and that doesn't work either!
<div id="container">
<div id="headerBar">
<P> this is a pretty header </p>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap">
<div id="mainContent">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>                 
</div>
</div>
<!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats -->
<div id="footer">
<P> This is the footer</P>
<!-- end #footer -->
</div>
<!-- end #container -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The `<script>` block that holds your main javascript content includes the following attribute: `language="text/javascript"`. This should be: `type="text/javascript"`
- The reference to the element should be `document.getElementById('map_canvas'));` not `document.getElementById('container.page-wrap.mainContent.map_canvas'));`
- I'm not sure how you're intending on triggering `drawVisualization`, but consider this: `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);` which will call the function on load.

With those changes the code runs. Hope that helps!